# Heroku Review Apps Url

Tags: heroku, heroku-api

We use a Heroku pipeline for deployment review apps for our Angular app. Recently we invested in EndTest codeless automation and we need to run the test suites on every review app that is created. The url's of these review apps are dynamic in Heroku, is there a way to capture this generated url and then execute a script that would trigger my test case suite in EndTest(EndTest has an API which can consume the url).

How do I get this done in Heroku environment. I just have PROC file configured.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [postdeploy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#the-postdeploy-script) script:

> The app.json file has a scripts section that lets you specify a postdeploy command. Use this to run any one-time setup tasks that make the app, and any databases, ready and useful for testing. Postdeploy is handy for one-off tasks, such as:
>
> - Setting up OAuth clients and DNS
> - Loading seed/test data into the review app’s test database

But if you will run this script with each change to a pull request, use [release phase](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase).

The app name should be in the env variable HEROKU_APP_NAME.